# How to copy one specific column after filtering results with Autofilter - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy, autofilter

I am in dire need of assistance after a couple of hours of trying. I am new to VBA and this is my problem.
I have a table with 20 columns (A to T) but with an undefined number of rows (they will add over time), my goal is to filter the data based on 2 criteria: first criteria is in column 6 (F2) - city name and second criteria is in column 11 (K2) - month, but not formated as time, just text, after that I want to copy only the visible results of column 20 (T2) to the second sheet of the workbook. The problem for me is that when I run the code all the columns are copied (A to T).
Here is the code that I used:

```
Sub copy_filtered_data()
Dim count_col, count_row As Integer
Dim orig, output As Worksheet


Worksheets("Intrari").Activate

Set orig = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Intrari")
Set output = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raport")

count_col = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)))
count_row = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)))

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Cells(2, 28).Value
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=Cells(2, 29).Value

orig.Range("T1") = Cells(count_row, 20).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
output.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: `Cells(count_row, 20).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy` - if you call SpecialCells on one cell, it will return everything... call it on the column. Though I'm not sure what the `orig.Range("T1") = ` is doing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here that may be causing you problems, including unqualified ranges, syntax issues and un-typed variables. Try the below code.

```
Sub copy_filtered_data()

Dim orig as Worksheet, output As Worksheet

Set orig = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Intrari")
Set output = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raport")

Dim count_col as Long, count_row As Long

count_col = orig.Cells(1,orig.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
count_row = orig.Cells(orig.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row

orig.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=orig.Cells(2, 28).Value
orig.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=orig.Cells(2, 29).Value

orig.Range("T1:T" & count_row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
output.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried the code above but I am getting a syntax error.

Comment: @Mika - which line?

Comment: count_col = WorksheetFunction.CountA(orig.Range("A1"), orig.Range("A1").End(xlToRight)))
count_row = WorksheetFunction.CountA(orig.Range("A1"), orig.Range("A1").End(xlDown)))

Comment: If necessary I can post the file.

Comment: @Mika - okay. I took that code directly from your source pretty much. The `WorksheetFunction` needs to be proceeded by `Application`. Anyway, I made edits to make it easier to get the row and column.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are the best. That solved my problem. Thank you very much! I am quite new to  this domain, not even a neophyte I would say. But again, thank you!